# Calculate constant from PDF

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, density-function

The PDF of a random variable X is given by:

$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
2 & : -c \le x < 0\\
2e^{-4x} & : 0 \le x < \infty\\
\end{array}
\right.$$

In this example, how would I calculate the value of c?

In all of the previous examples I've encountered in the book, they are of the form of:

$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
c(4x - 2x^2) & : 0 \le x < 2\\
0 & : otherwise\\
\end{array}
\right.$$

In the above example, I would just solve for the value of c through the following integration:

$$c\int_0^2{(4x - 2x^2)dx} = 1$$

Comment: We're supposed to give guidance and hints rather than complete solutions for these, so here's some guidance: you know the area under the whole pdf must be 1. Compute the area of the right hand part. Now you know what the area of the left hand part must be (since they add to 1). Now compute $c$ in a similar fashion to what you've done before.

Comment: I tried but it is difficult to get the idea across without some computation.

Comment: Thanks y'all! I've been trying to wrap my head around this problem for an hour, but now the answer is very clear! @Michael, I appreciate you giving me helpful hints, rather than the full solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case the first part is $2c$ (area of the rectangle). Then calculate the integral of $2 e^{-4x}$ from $c$ to infinity. That part will be in closed form ${2\over{4}} -0$.  So calculate $c$ as $2c+{1\over{2}} = 1$. Since the entire integral must equal $1$.

Answer (score 4):

In order to solve for the value $c$ in the PDF

$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
2 & : -c \le x < 0\\
2e^{-4x} & : 0 \le x < \infty\\
\end{array}
\right.$$

It would seem proper to first find the stepwise CDF $F(X)$ by integrating each part separately. i.e.

$$F(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\int{2} dx & : -c \le x < 0\\
\int2e^{-4x} dx & : 0 \le x < \infty\\
\end{array}
\right.$$

this results in the CDF being 
$$F(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\int{2} dx & : -c \le x < 0\\
\int2e^{-4x} dx & : 0 \le x < \infty\\
\end{array}
\right.$$

Which also means that:

$$\int_{-c}^0 2dx +\int_0^\infty 2e^{-4x} dx=1$$

After integration this is:

$$2c+{1\over{2}}=1$$

Solving for $c$ gives

$$c={1\over{4}}$$

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: This is even more explicit but doesn't try to give hints either.